# Guru Josh Project - Infinity 2008 meaning

Tags: lyrics, meaning, electronic-music

Does anyone know meaning of the lyrics to the song Infinity 2008 by the Guru Josh Project?

Answer (score 2):

Infinity 2008 was the 2nd remix of [Infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinity_(Guru_Josh_song)), first released in 1989.  While there is no canonical answer, the lyrics are pretty simple:

```
Here's my key
Philosophy
A freak like me
Just needs infinity

Relax
Take your time

And take your time
To trust in me
And you will find
Infinity, infinity

The time goes by
So naturally
Why you'll receive
Infinity
```

These are repeated several times.  Being that it's Techno, the lyrics don't have to mean anything as long as they progress the beat.  However, if they're supposed to be coherent, my best guess is that it's about relationships.  Being infinitely happy with someone forever.

Comment: It seems to me more likely to be about achieving some altered mental state, possibly via the use of naughty substances!

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Answer (score 2):

When you are able to relax and take your time, meaning look inside where there is no time and space you will find infinity.

He clearly states it, 'Here's is my key , philosophy a freak like me needs infinity'

He says that the his own way of living is not normal , because he is a freak as he said, and that he found his own key of existence.

The last 6 months i am very deep into meditation and spiritual awakening and i am pretty sure that those simple lyrics are not just beat. I can almost feel what the artist felt when wrote them.
What we experience it is just a 3-D reality, it is a perspective of a massive picture. The way to see the whole picture is via inner exploration.

The only way to experience infinity is by self love and connecting to the divine, the Unity.

The sad/strange thing here is that Guru Josh suicide.
Probably he believed that dying will reach something greater, but my opinion is that there is greatness in every reality and that according to what angle we see the picture every time we must fully experience it.